# Flutter says fontFamily is not defined when it IS?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have done everything step bye step and it still says "undefined name 'Pacifico'"

[heres what is see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D97ZY.png)

pubspec file:

```
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
     - images/


  fonts:
    - family: Pacifico
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf
```

It loads fine

main.dart

```
body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 50.0,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/me.2.png'),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Ahmed",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: Pacifico,
                    //HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )),
```

Comment: If you put single quotes around the fontFamily name: `fontFamily: 'Pacifico'`, that should solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*There are 2 possible solutions to check.*

*1*. Make sure that your *font's* path is *correct*.

*2*. The way I use my `fontFamily` is by adding them in my `Theme` of my `MaterialApp` or `CupertinoApp`. By doing this you don't have to specifically type out the `fontFamily` for each `text` widget and I would assume that you are going to use this `font` throughout the entire `app` anyway.

```
MaterialApp(
        title: 'My app',
        theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: 'Pacfico',
        ),
   );
```